# Issue when login a site using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to automate a site login for test and  I am using C# and Selenium ChromeWebDriver.

My code is down below here:

```
ChromeOptions options = new();
options.AddArgument("--incognito");
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
options.AddArgument("--disable-site-isolation-trials");
options.AddArgument("--disable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess");
//options.AddArgument("--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt");
//options.AddArgument("--allow-reading-third-party-cookies");
//options.AddArgument("--allow-third-party-cookies");

ChromeDriver driver = new("./", options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new(driver);

driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://xxxx.xx.xx");

//WebDriverWait wait = new(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

If I run this code, I am navigated to the Url and if I input login credentials and click sign in button, no result is shown up just like the sign in button has no functionality.

I opened my dev panel and I can see the request is posting every time I press the sign in button, but no result:

The header of request is:

```
Request URL: https://xxxx.xx.xx/authprovider/webtoken
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I tried it on my normal chrome browser, incognito mode, guest mode and everything was working fine.

If all things go well, the request header must be like this:

```
Request URL: https://xxxx.xx.xx/authprovider/webtoken
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK (from service worker)
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

And there is also response header incoming too.

I searched for answer for over 10 hours, but still can't this problem.

I am new to Selenium and I can't even make my first step.

Please if anyone has experienced with this problem or anyone expert, give me correct guide about this problem.

**EDIT:**

If thing go well, the bearer token should be received as response, but no response is coming.

And the response should be coming in like this:

```
access_token : "5a1e5347-49f8-4a3f-becf-da1f43079279"
expires_in : 4404
message : "SUCESS"
refresh_token : "95f72d9f-694a-4953-8f18-c010500f1a64"
token_type : "bearer"
```

Comment: Is it just when selenium tries to click the button? Or have you tried doing it manually

Comment: I tired both. First, I thought auto clicking the sign in button would work well, but it didn't. So I blocked the clicking sign in button part and I clicked manually and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: May I ask you why didn't you share the code lines where you inserting the credentials and clicking the login button, not shared the link to that page and set the `WebDriverWait` timeout for 1 second?

Comment: That's because I have blocked all the codes below, first I automatically filled up the username and password fields and even click sign in button automatically. But it was not going correct so I blocked them. It WORKS when chromedriver is not attached, it DOESN'T WORK when the browser is opened by chromedriver. Hope you dig into my problem, it there is any sensible idea, don't be shy to answer my question.

Comment: Some sites can detect if you are using Selenium. Maybe that is what happens?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to detect the selenium, but instead of running a chrome browser in selenium test mode, I created a chrome process with debugging address and made selenium attached to it. Well, it works fine well because the browser is started as a normal browser, but I found it uncomfortable to turn off all chrome browsers before starting my chrome process. If I don't do it, the selenium can't find the chrome process. Isn't there any flexible way of doing this?